# Need help addressing cors issue on server

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a django backend with react frontend. I am trying to deploy my application on cpanel hosting. I have created subdomain for backend (api.example.com/) and main domain (example.com/) is for frontend. PS: mentioned fake URL. Following is what my settings.py looks like,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Custom Installed
    "corsheaders",
...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'www.example.com',
    'example.com',
    'xxx.yyy.208.227',
]

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
# CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://www.example.com',
    'https://example.com',
    'https://xxx.yyy.208.227',
]
```

I am seeing error as mentioned below,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/products/' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Client Code:

```
export const getAxiosInstance = () => {
    let retryCount = 0;
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: BASE_URL,
        withCredentials: true,
    });
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(`${TAG} Token from getAxiosInstance ${token}`);
    if (!token) {
        return axiosInstance;
    }
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp, error => {
        console.log(`getAxiosInstance Intercepting ${error}`);
        if (error.response.status === 403 && retryCount < 3) {
            retryCount++;
            axiosInstance.post(REFRESH, {}, {withCredentials: true}).then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    setDefaultAuthHeader(response.data.token);
                    return axios(error.config);
                }
            });
        }
        if (retryCount >= 3) {
            alert('Login again!');
        }
        return error;
    });
    return axiosInstance;
}
.
.
.
const axiosInstance = getAxiosInstance();
axiosInstance.get('/api/products').then(response => {
    // Doing something
})
.
.
.
```

Even with following configuration, I am having same issue,
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: List `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` first in `MIDDLEWARE`.

Comment: Moved it but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, but you're one step closer to solving your problem. The most likely source of the issue is that your client includes a request header that is not allowed in your CORS configuration. Please add the relevant client code to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the client side code as well. PS: I am fairly new to react + Django + web services, so I apologize for some basic problems I am missing.

Comment: Try dropping `withCredentials: true` everywhere; you most likely do not need it. Also, try listing `"content-type"` and `"authorization"` in your `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`. See https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/#cors-allow-headers-sequence-str

Comment: Removed the withCredentials:true and tried with configuration as seen in the screenshot above, but still no luck. I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Instead of using `"*"`, try listing `"content-type"` and `"authorization"`, as suggested in my earlier comment.

Comment: @jub0bs those two headers are in the default value for that setting...

Comment: Why does your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting contain the **same** domain names as `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`? You do understand one setting is about the allowed domain names that can be used to address the **current server** and the other is about the **other origins** that are allowed to make requests right? Your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting should have `api.example.com` in the list from what you are saying. I am guessing that if you look at the console for the OPTIONS request you got a 400 status code other than the CORS error itself?